# How to add a class css into directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that I use to change text of an input to `uppercase`, it works fine, but now I want to show the text `capitalize` when user type, note that I want to keep the text uppercase but to show to user it should to be capitalize. To do this I created a css class but I don't know how to use this css into directive.

How could I add this css class into directive ?

trying.

**CSS**

```
.textCapitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

**Directive**

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.directive('uiUppercase', function(){

    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){         
            element.addClass('textCapitalize'); //show text capitalized
            var _textFormat = function(input){
                return input.length > 0 ? input.toUpperCase() : "";
            }

            element.bind('keyup', function(){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(_textFormat(ctrl.$viewValue));               
                ctrl.$render();
            });

        }

    };

});
```

Comment: If you add the capitalize class, its already being capitalize. Do you mean to uppercase the model value at the background and not visible to the user?

Comment: Exactly, I want the value stay uppercase on background but to user does value is visible as capitalize.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.directive('uiUppercase', function() {
   return {

      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',

      link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

        function addUpperCaseClass(ngModelValue) {

            if(!element.hasClass("textCapitalize"))
                element.addClass("textCapitalize");
        }
        ctrl.$parsers.push(addUpperCaseClass);

      }
   };
});
```